# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't show edited/added icon

Tags: .net, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am connected to 2013 TFS on Visual Studio 2017. Everything is well except I don't see the icons next to the files. 
It should have the lock icon on the unedited files, check for edited, and the plus icon for the added files. I don't see any of these icons.
If I edit a file, it shows up on the Pending change. but if I add a new one, I need to manually add it to TFS.

any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are talking about the icons as below:

[image]

> If I edit a file, it shows up on the Pending change. but if I add a
> new one, I need to manually add it to TFS.

According to your description, this may related to **source control binding** of the project. Try to unbind/bind the project which may do the trick.

*Under File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control.*

Another way is editing .csproj file. There is a section missing in the .csproj file that should look something like this:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

It only affects the display of the Source Control status in the Solution Explorer as noted you can already perform other source control tasks on the project. It's not much but worth fixing as it's a good visual check that everything is being controlled.

More details you could also take a look at this similar question: [No padlock icon for some projects in a source controlled solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035650/no-padlock-icon-for-some-projects-in-a-source-controlled-solution)